# How to work with an array inside of another array?

Tags: arrays, json, transformation, jolt

I'm having problems while working with a nested array inside another array on a JSON document. I need to obtain an array containing one JSON document with the "CandidateEmail" and the "ApplicationId" "JobRefNumber". I think that the example below will help you understand better.

My input is:

```json
{
  "Content": [
    {
      "CandidateEmail": "john1@noexist.com",
      "Applications": [
        {
          "ApplicationId": "app1",
          "JobRefNumber": "REF1"
        },
        {
          "ApplicationId": "app2",
          "JobRefNumber": "REF2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CandidateEmail": "carl2@email.com",
      "Applications": [
        {
          "ApplicationId": "app3",
          "JobRefNumber": "REF3"
        },
        {
          "ApplicationId": "app4",
          "JobRefNumber": "REF4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected output is:

```json
[
  {
    "CandidateEmail": "john1@noexist.com",
    "ApplicationId": "app1",
    "JobRefNumber": "REF1"
  },
  {
    "CandidateEmail": "john1@noexist.com",
    "ApplicationId": "app2",
    "JobRefNumber": "REF2"
  },
  {
    "CandidateEmail": "carl2@email.com",
    "ApplicationId": "app3",
    "JobRefNumber": "REF3"
  },
  {
    "CandidateEmail": "carl2@email.com",
    "ApplicationId": "app4",
    "JobRefNumber": "REF4"
  }
]
```

I don't know if it will be of any help, but here is the spec I've been able to draft so far:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Content": {
        "*": {
          "Applications": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,CandidateEmail)": "[&1].CandidateEmail",
              "ApplicationId": "[&1].ApplicationId",
              "JobRefNumber": "[&1].JobRefNumber"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Content": {
        "*": {
          "Appl*": {
            "*": {
              "@2,CandidateEmail": "&3[#2].CandidateEmail", // you an go two levels up the tree to reach the level of CandidateEmail 
              "*": "&3[#2].&" // distinguish by indexes of "Applications" and "Content" arrays through use of [#2] and &3 respectively. Replicate the keys by using &, and all attributes nested within innermost objects by using * wildcards.
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {// get rid of the keys of wrapper arrays and objects
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```